# GTM how to disable default events from js?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

My question is about GTM

[image]

`gtm.linkCLick`, `gtm.click` and `custom.timer` are those defaults?

If yes, is there any way to disable defaults from javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gtm.linkClick and gtm.click are built-in events and variables. In your Google Tag Manager Workspace, select the menu option variables on the left side, and click Configure.

[image: GTM Variables]

Deselect the Click variables to disable gtm.linkClick and gtm.click.
[image: GTM click variables selected]

custom.timer seems to be code on the website that pushes information to the dataLayer. If this is the case, you need to remove it from the code.
If it is a tag configuration, you can remove or preferably pause the tag.
[image: GTM pause tag]

Make sure that by disabling stuff in GTM you do not break essential tag configurations that are collecting important data..